# is this a good practice to output html using php?

Tags: php, html, format

This is just out of curiosity and wonder if doing things like this would be good or what's the best alternative way.

I have an html which would output a few div the same way but having a few different values or classes.

For example this is my html

```
    <div class="kit-side-a">
        <p class="header">Side A</p>
        <div class="position">
            <select name="select-kits" class="select-kits kit-a">
                <option value="" group="kits">No Kit Needed</option>
                <option value="k1" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-1</option>
                <option value="k2" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-2</option>
                <option value="k3" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-3</option>
                <option value="k4" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end kit side a -->

    <div class="kit-side-b">
        <p class="header">Side B</p>
        <div class="position">
            <select name="select-kits" class="select-kits kit-b">
                <option value="" group="kits">No Kit Needed</option>
                <option value="k1" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-1</option>
                <option value="k2" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-2</option>
                <option value="k3" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-3</option>
                <option value="k4" group="kits">Set Kit - #FKS1439-4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end kit side b -->
```

as can see these two are identical but only difference is their side classes

I made something like this in php

```
function printKitSelections($sideClass, $sideLabel, $selectMountSide){
    $output[] = "<div class='$sideClass'>";
    $output[] = "<p class='header'>$sideLabel</p>";
    $output[] = "<div class='position'>";
    $output[] = "<select name='select-kits' class='select-kits $selectMountSide'>";
    $output[] = "<option value='' group='kits'>No Kit Needed</option>";
    $output[] = "<option value='k1' group='kits'>Set Kit - #FKS1439-1</option>";
    $output[] = "<option value='k2' group='kits'>Set Kit - #FKS1439-2</option>";
    $output[] = "<option value='k3' group='kits'>Set Kit - #FKS1439-3</option>";
    $output[] = "<option value='k4' group='kits'>Set Kit - #FKS1439-4</option>";
    $output[] = "</select>";
    $output[] = "</div>";
    $output[] = "</div> <!-- end kit $sideLabel -->";

    return join('', $output);
}
```

which then in the html I can just do something like

```
<?php echo printKitSelections('kit-side-a', 'Side A', 'kit-a')?>
<?php echo printKitSelections('kit-side-b', 'Side B', 'kit-b')?>
```

But when I view the source code using the above, the source code is totally not formatted and instead just one LONG line.

So I am curious which way would be a better way or there is another alternative way of doing this that would be a lot better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By long file, do you mean a long single line? Do you have some sort of minification or compression on?

Comment: php supports multiline-string literals and [heredoc](http://docs.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) literals if that is your only concern.

Comment: Add new line characters: \r\n to each line, if you want that rendered source look nice....

Comment: @VolkerK, ahhh... maybe question is a duplicate, but on link you provided, selected answer suggest using of Smarty, which is not the best way today (and never was, imho), definitely. OP can get wrong picture... :)

Comment: @nevermind thanks :D but I mean like, which way would be a better way? use plain `html`? or using the `php function`? Also with the `\r\n` it's more readable but wouldn't look as nice with the tabs (Just curiosity everywhere sorry for the weirdo questions and wonders)

Comment: @nevermind: The imagined way to handle that situation was to post a better answer to the orignal question. But then this answer would need to get more votes, ideally even get the new accepted answer ...but it never seems to work out that way; at least not with the [php] tag ;-) plus: Those "discussions" usually get quite opinionated really fast.

Comment: @Dora, i would add your options (3 arguments in your function) to array, and use foreach loop, with alternative syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php, so, you can make HTML for divs, add 3 variables inside, and loop and print divs... something like that. :)

Comment: @nevermind I think I get what you mean, which I never done before and still trying to get my head around it.  I read the manual you gave me but still can't get my head around the array, do you think you can give me a sample with the array?

Comment: @nevermind I used phpfiddle and did something like this and only have it in my html file http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e2e0-1piu  do you mean something like this and just leave everything in html file?

Comment: Well... something like that, i would probably simplify things a little: i would make multidimensional array (array of arrays)$options=array(array('kit-side-a', 'Side A', 'kit-a'),array('kit-side-b', 'Side B', 'kit-b')); and then just check if $options are there and loop through it (foreach loop), you don't need $i var for incrementation.... But, basically, that's what i would do. Someone else maybe would use some template engine... I don't see any good reason for it.... :)